# Google Analytics: Time on site by day's hour?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to know this:

```
0 am - avg. time on site  = Xmins
1 am - avg. time on site  = Xmins
2 am - avg. time on site  = Xmins
3 am - avg. time on site  = Xmins
4 am - avg. time on site  = Xmins
5 am - avg. time on site  = Xmins
...
```

It would be nice to have it as a barchart in Google Analytics, but since there is a maximum set to nine bars in dashboard, it doesn't seem possible.

Might be a line chart, but there is no such grouping there, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Analytics to get the bounce rate by hour for any specific day:

1. Log into analytics
2. Click on the date picker and choose just a single day
3. Navigate to "Audience" -> "Overview"
4. Click on "Hourly" to see how the bounce rate changes over the course of the day.
5. Select "Avg. Visit Duration" from the drop down menu.

Here is a screenshot of this report for one of my websites:

[image: Screenshot of Google Analytics Hourly Average Time on Site]

Google Analytics does not have functionality to see each hour represented as an a average across many days.  A single day at a time is the best you will be able to do.

Comment: I was asking for time on site though. I found a way to see hourly aggregates in dashboard (I think), but I can't see all 12 hour there :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I edit the answer to get the correct metric you were looking for.

Comment: I guess there is no way to see it in agreggate over a few months period?

Comment: Not that I have found.

Comment: okay, this is as close as it gets, but not an answer so I am going to keep this open just in case and upvote your answer.